# How to update array element value for code to text translation javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, morse-code

I have this following code which creates a data structure that represents relationship between characters in
plain text and characters in a 5x5 matrix code:

```js
let tapcode = [
  [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
  [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
  [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
  [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
  [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
  [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
];
//row 1
tapcode[1][1] = "e";
tapcode[1][2] = "t";
tapcode[1][3] = "a";
tapcode[1][4] = "n";
tapcode[1][5] = "d";
//row 2
tapcode[2][1] = "o";
tapcode[2][2] = "i";
tapcode[2][3] = "r";
tapcode[2][4] = "u";
tapcode[2][5] = "c";
//row3
tapcode[3][1] = "s";
tapcode[3][2] = "h";
tapcode[3][3] = "m";
tapcode[3][4] = "f";
tapcode[3][5] = "p";
//row 4
tapcode[4][1] = "l";
tapcode[4][2] = "y";
tapcode[4][3] = "g";
tapcode[4][4] = "v";
tapcode[4][5] = "j";
//row 5
tapcode[5][1] = "w";
tapcode[5][2] = "b";
tapcode[5][3] = "x";
tapcode[5][4] = "q";
tapcode[5][5] = "z";
```

My question is how can I use the sum of `tapcode[5][4] + tapcode[2][5]` (`"qc"`) to represent the string `"k"` and also the sum of `tapcode[5][1] + tapcode[2][4] + tapcode[5][1]` (`"wuw"`) to represent a space string (`"  "`)?

Thanks any advice will be appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Post your code as plain text, not an image. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting for code formatting help.

Comment: Please explain the logic of `qc` representing `k`.

Comment: You can use an object that maps strings to a set of indexes, e.g. `{ k: [5,4,2,5] }`

Comment: please remember arrays have zero base indices.

Comment: What's the point of the matrix? Why don't you just have direct mappings: `{ "k": "qc", " ": "wuw", ...}`?

Comment: I want to use "qc" to represent "k" as i do not want to modify the tapcode array structure to accomodate "k". Same thing with using "wuw" to represent a space.

Comment: @AabirChowdhury But why does `qc` represents `k`? Please share the exact logic.

Comment: @gurvinder372 "qc" is chosen to represent k because there are no words that contain the letters q and c consecutively.

Comment: @AabirChowdhury But how does your computer (or your method) know that there are no words containing `qc`?

Comment: @gurvinder372 The code is actually for a mobile web app which converts taps on a mobile screen into text. Here is the matrix which shows the corresponding letters for taps :  https://imgur.com/a/KuH9Q

Comment: what is the input on the screen, the letters or the numbers? what happens to just letters?